# How to copy artifacts from NPM build to .NET Core deploy in TSFS

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, devops

I've set up build steps compiling my .NET Core application, followed by steps for Npm install and Npm build. All pass and as far I can tell by the logs, everything goes well.

I can't find a suitable build step for moving the transpiled JS in my dist directory to wwwroot directory of the main project. Where is it, what is it called and how do I move over the artifact from Npm build step to where it's going to be served?

The solution I'm working on has the structure of a main project called *Api* (that's where the backend is developed) and an directory **within the solution's directory but not in the project's directory** called *Web*. (I found no way to add a *Web* project to VS solution without VS adding PROJ files and thinking it's a DLL or something.)

So I need to copy files like this.

> /Solution/Web/dist/* -> /Solution/Api/wwwroot

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through Copy File task directly (Specify Source Folder and Target Folder).

On the other hand, you may consider using Gulp to do it: [Use Gulp in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-gulp?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I ended up running a PowerShell step doing that. Gult feels so 2017, hehe. The trick was also to copy **before** building the solution. Otherwise, the copied files are not brought into the deployed site.